# How to add a socket as QTCaptureOutputs for a QTCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video-streaming, video-capture, qtkit

I'm reading Apple's documentation on using QTKit to capture streaming audio and video from input sources. I read that the central class `QTCaptureSession` handles the input and sends it to every possible output (`QTCaptureOutput`). The documentation lists six subclasses of `QTCaptureOutput` (e.g., `QTCaptureMovieFileOutput`).

I would like to create a subclass of `QTCaptureOutput` to write to an `NSSocket` so I could send the video stream over to another machine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTCaptureOutput` does not strike me as a class designed to be subclassed outside of QTKit. Instead, you can try dumping the data to a local domain socket in the file system using a `QTCaptureFileOutput` object, and simultaneously pulling the data from that local domain socket and sending it over to the remote machine.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. You said QTCaptureFileOutput, but could I use QTCaptureVideoFileOutput? (i'm only interested in the video)

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: Now that I'm reading your answer I see that you say to use local socket (using QTCaptureFileOutput) and then pulling data from that socket and sending to the remote machine. Couldn't I just use QTCaptureFileOutput to dump data on a remote socket?

Comment: If you can convince `QTCaptureFileOutput` that the remote socket is, in fact, a file. Unfortunately, it expects a file URL, not an `NSOutputStream`.